# Wrap figure vertical alignment of text

Tags: vertical-alignment, wrapfigure

The text is slightly higher than the image when initially starting the sentence. I have tried using vspace or \ to lower the sentence. But it just moves the whole image down with the text. Is there some simple fix like a package i'am missing. If i were to start the wrapfig on a new page the problem is gone though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\graphicspath{{F}}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}



 \clearpage
\subsubsection{Stepped Nozzle}
bla blah blah

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[scale=.6]{liggy}
    \caption{Ligament case}
\end{wrapfigure}

In figure 4.16, the stepped nozzle has produced a vast amount of ligaments on the bottom angle. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of problem]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is governed by the `\intextsep` length. You can set it to zero to avoid the empty space above and below the `wrapfig` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
    \caption{Ligament case}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If you wish the change to stay local (which I would advise), you can wrap the `\setlength`, the `wrapfig` and the paragraph which is to be wrapped around the figure inside a group:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
{%
    \setlength\intextsep{0pt}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
        \caption{Ligament case}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent\lipsum[1]%
}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Lastly, you could also put a negative `\vspace` inside the `wrapfig` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
    \caption{Ligament case}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The caveat of this solution is that if the `wrapfig` is at the top of a new page, it will be shifted above the first line (so you need to remove the `\vspace` command). Also, it requires you to manually determine the appropriate amount by which to shift manually (`\baselineskip` is probably what you usually want though).

As a side note: I would generally not set `\parindent` to zero globally, unless you really want it to be zero everywhere, but instead use a `\noindent` before a paragraph which is not supposed to start with an indented line.

**Edit**:

Result for the second code snippet:

[image: code result]

**EDIT 2**:

The reason why you'd almost certainly want your changes to `\intextsep` to stay local is that it is a LaTeX length for governing float behavior, not something specific to `wrapfig`. As per Lamport in *LaTeX - A Document Preparation System*:

> `\intextsep` The vertical space placed above and below a float that is
>   put in the middle of the text with the `h` location option. It is a
>   rubber length.

(p.200, Section C.9.1)

**EDIT 3:**

In response to user's comment, here's the code which produces the desired result for me when doing this multiple times:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
{%
    \setlength\intextsep{0pt}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
        \caption{Ligament case}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent\lipsum[1]%
}

\lipsum[2]

{%
    \setlength\intextsep{0pt}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pic}
        \caption{Ligament case}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent\lipsum[1]%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay first of all thank you very much for solving my question so quickly. I tried adding another wrap fig below in order to show another example, so I copied the same code but line reappeared for the second wrap fig. I tried setting the \intextsep command again but I don't see any changes?

Comment: Okay just tried the  \vspace{-\baselineskip} twice and its solved thankssss

Comment: @user In the second `wrapfig`, did you set `\intextsep` to zero also the second time (you need to set it to zero for each `wrapfig` if you put it inside `{...}`)? Because it works for me if I do it like that. Specifically, if you're using the second code example, you need to copy everything from `{% \setlength\intextsep{0pt ... wrapfig ... \noindent\lipsum[1]}` (or whichever text you have instead of `\lipsum`, of course). I'm glad that the other way works for you though.

Comment: @user I have added a code example with two `wrapfig`s which works for me.

Comment: When I replace my \lipsum with my own text, the images get pushed to the left, nearly outside the document?

Comment: @user Hard to say what's causing that without a compilable example, I haven't really been able to break mine. If the figure gets pushed into the margin, you could try adding a negative `overhang` parameter: `\begin{wrapfigure}{l}[-5mm]{0.45\textwidth}`. Also, make sure the `width` parameters both of the `wrapfigure` and the `\includegraphics` are sensible. The `scale` option didn't really work for me, which is why I changed it to `width=0.45\textwidth`. Otherwise, you'll probably need to paste the code you're currently trying to compile.

Comment: Is there any way to set `\intextsep` to zero _globally_ but _only_ for wrapfigure? Because putting every wrapfigure into `{...}` doesn't work, if I'm not having pure text around the wrapfigures all the time. As I use a lot of lists, that happens quite frequently and the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` solution seems so unelegant to me.

Comment: @EmeraJade You could maybe try to have a look at the code of `wrapfigure` itself and create your own `wrapfigure` environment which takes this into account based on that code.

Comment: @alpenwasser That has already been done, however it didn't solve the issue :(
I summarised all related questions in my own question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415398/adjust-intextsep-for-wrapfigure-only