# Extra vertical space using wrapfigure environment

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{test.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
2. test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
3. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
4. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
5. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
\end{document}
```

Codes above give such result:

[image: result 1]

But If I add a sentence before `wrapfigure` environment, it will give extra vertical space like this:

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\noindent
1. test test test test test test test test test test\par
\noindent
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{test.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
2. test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
3. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
4. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
5. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result 2]

I tried to use `vspace*` in `wrapfigure` environment, but it didn't work.

So how to remove that extra vertical space?

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `insbox` plain TeX macro package doesn't have this problem: it defines the `\InsertBoxL` and `\InsertBoxR` commands, which take two mandatory arguments: the number of unshortened lines before  insertion of the box, and the inserted object, and a *last* optional argument – the number of supplementary shorter lines, in case TeX calculates  the wrong number of shorter lines.

Note that, as the inserted image is not a float, if you need a caption, you will have to use `\captionof{figure}{…}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{1}{ \includegraphics[width=3cm]{sunstar}}
\noindent
1. test test test test test test test test test test\par
\noindent
2. test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
3. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
4. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\
5. test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The extra vertical spacing stems from the `\intextsep` length. Setting this to zero removes the space.

For more information, you might want to check out [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365753/wrap-figure-vertical-alignment-of-text) Stack Exchange question.